# R: How to call a function with a string and paste parameters to this function?

Tags: r

Sounds probably more complicated than what I want to achieve :) Since I do a lot of formatting to my plots I want to wrap this all in a function. However some formatting and setting of parameters is done before the plotn call and adding the legend and icon as well as formatting them is done after the plot call. So I basically want a function like:

```
myFormattedPlots<-function(plotFunctionName, plotFunctionParameters...)
```

The parameters list depends of course on the function..but I image something like this:

```
myFormattedPlots<-function("plot.xts",MyXTSTimeSeries){
   par(xpd=FALSE)
...
plot.xts(MyXTSTimeSeries)
grid.raster(logo,x=c(0.05),y=c(0.02),width=0.05,height=0.03)
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why don't you pass directly the plot function to your function myFormattedPlots instead of its name? It's so easy in R

Comment: can you show me an example? Never did that before...

Comment: I suggest you also study `...` and `do.call` as those could be quite useful for your purpose.

Comment: See my answer for an example

Answer (score 4):

You can give the function instead of its name in R. It would be that easy on your example:

```
myFormattedPlots<-function(func,MyXTSTimeSeries){
   par(xpd=FALSE)
   func(MyXTSTimeSeries)
   grid.raster(logo,x=c(0.05),y=c(0.02),width=0.05,height=0.03)
}
myFormattedPlots(plot.xts, your.time.series)
```